# C++ shared structure - Good practice

Tags: c++, struct, constants, shared-ptr

I have a struct that is read from a JSON file (can be heavy).

And this struct is used from various class objects I'm using.
My concern is:

How should I pass this struct to constructors for them to be able to read (only) it? While avoiding copying the data?

I first found myself passing raw pointers to the struct, and someone saw my code and told me to slap my hand whenever I touch raw pointers.

So what is the appropriate way of doing so? reference? shared_ptr?

Comment: const reference.

Comment: @liliscent Thank you, I can have a const ref class member right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, slap that someone on the face. There is **nothing** wrong with raw non-owning pointers.

For your particular case, you might be better off using a const reference, and it even might be more idiomatic, depending on your actual code. Haven't seen the code, can't say more about your particular situation.

Comment: I might want to skip the part of slapping my manager but thanks, I can use this const ref to initialize a const ref struct class member right?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Practically I would not, because const reference can be bound to temporary object, so you will hold a reference to the temporary. For anything which outlives the call site, I would use the pointer.'

Comment: Then I'm safe, all my objects live in a kind of main function call.

Comment: I'd say the problem with raw pointers is that they might become dangling pointers if the pointed-to-object gets deleted while some other code still has access to it.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner so much with dangling references. This is the language we choose for our trade. You can opt for garbage collection language and forget such problems forever.

Comment: I opted for using smart pointers and haven't had any problems with dangling references (or memory leaks) since then.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner code which indiscriminately uses `shared_ptr` (when shared ownership is not required) is very hard to reason about, and suffers from pessimisations due to unnecessary memory barriers. Of course, you can structure your code anyway you want.